# Extract n top elements from dictionary

Tags: python

I have created a `dictionary` in python. I have sorted the dictionary with the following instruction.

```
dict = {}

dict[identifier] = dst
sorted_dict = sorted(dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
print sorted_dict
```

Here `identifier` is `key` and `dst` is a `value`

I want to retrieve first `N` elements from the dictionary. How I can do that?

Comment: `print(sorted_dict[:N])`?

Comment: wouldnt it be easier to use `Counter`?

Comment: @Netwave it would, which is why I'm disappointed the answer below parroting Aran-Fey's comment has 2 upvotes and no one's offered a Counter-based solution yet.

Comment: slicing works. thanks @Aran-Fey

Comment: that shows brassiness. If an answer can get 2 upvote, why not the question

Comment: duplicate questions can be deleted? @Aran-Fey

Comment: @cswah we optimise for pearls, not sand.

Comment: @cswah You're asking if you should delete your question? You don't have to; it can be a useful signpost.

Comment: @cswah No, duplicates are good to broaden the target area for the general problem with this solution. Broaden for people googling, I mean.

Comment: thanks!!!. Can't understand why it is voted down.

Comment: @cswah downvoting is used to filter questions from the frontpage. The people who did so probably meant to convey 'this question is a duplicate, don't bother looking at it.' It doesn't feel good, but it's not meant to judge you, just a tool to manage this site.

Comment: @cswah don't worry about the downvotes, here on SO people with high rep thinks they own this site and do whatever they want to do without even reading q, because of these kind of people So is becoming hard for new users

Comment: Some people (not me) downvote common duplicate questions that are easy to find with a simple search, because it shows that you didn't do much research before posting your question.

Comment: @akashkarothiya As Arne said, duplicate _questions_ aren't so bad, because once they're closed they can help people to find the linked "target" page. But _answers_ on duplicate questions are not so good because it scatters the answers over many pages, making them harder to find and harder to compare. And it means that the answers aren't fairly competing with each other for votes.

Comment: I totally understand, however my question more generic in nature than already answered question.

Comment: Agreed @PM2Ring thanks for clarifying :)

Comment: @akashkarothiya You may enjoy reading [my Meta SO post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322110/4014959) on this topic. ;)

Comment: @PM2Ring much helpful, you are such a gem (I admire you alot) :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `slicing` to extract `n` elements of the list

```
>>> print(sorted_dict[:n])
```

Comment: don't be angry, it was just a working example. @coldspeed

Comment: sorry about that @coldspeed OP asked in python 2, that's why I answered in python 2, I will take care of this next time :(

Comment: @cswah Umm, that comment applies to you too, please see [here](https://pythonclock.org)

Answer (score 2):

[`collectons.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) It's the way to go:

```
from collections import Counter
count_dict = Counter(the_dict)
print(count_dict.most_common(n))
```

Here you have a [live example](https://repl.it/repls/CyanHandsomeMonads)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Also note that the Counter works best with numeric values, and you only need to create once instead of sorting repeatedly.

Comment: @coldspeed, yes, actually, does it works on O(n) right?

Comment: Yes, for any k < n, it should return elements from a heap in O(k) time.